# Single SQL insert command with varying columns

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns, sql-insert

I know that it is possible to insert multiple rows with one SQL insert command, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```

However, I am trying to find a way to do the same thing when the ***column list*** is different for each row, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2 ), (Column3, Column4) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value3, Value4 )
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify all columns and provide `NULL/default` for missing values:

```
INSERT INTO tab(col1,col2,col3,col4)
VALUES (1, 2, default, default)
      ,(default, default, 3, 4);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=21d6e594cfb809835e8ac4ac7634e9e2)**